# How to use the generated .so library in another Android Project?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I’ve followed **http://kn-gloryo.github.io/Build_NDK_AndroidStudio_detail/** and it works well! However, I want to use the generated .so library in a new Android application, and I simply don’t know how to do this...  I’ve been struggling for days and if any step-by-step tutorial can be shared that would be helpful!

This is the Android Project **MyApp** which I used to generate the .so files:

[image]

MainActivity :

[image]

Java Class : MyNDK

[image]

header file: com_demo_ble_myapp_MyNDK.h

[image]

Cpp file: MyLibrary

[image]

And this is the structure of my new Android project **useSOLib**, I simply copy all the so files from **MyApp\app\src\main\libs** to **useSoLib\app\src\main\jniLibs**

[image]

And this is MainActivity in useSoLib:

[image]

I can Build-> Make Project successfully, but when I run it on the device, the app shows "Unfortunately, useSoLib has stopped." and crushed. I know I miss some steps here, but I'm new to Android Studio so I have no clue where I should start with... thank you in advance for any suggestions!  :)

Comment: Probably there's something wrong with your native code. Have you tried to use log or gdb to check which line of your code caused the exception?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In the MainActivety of the project MyApp(which I used to generate .so library),  I’ve newed an instance of MyNDK, called the native function getMyString, and it runs successfully on the device, I can also see the correct returned String in my logcat, so I assume the native C++ function works well. Just when I try to access the generated .so library from other Android project with a different package name, it crushed... I also add my header and cpp files above for reference.

Comment: Your code is wrong. See my answer. You have to export the Java Class and import it into your new project with the *.so file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import **MyNDK** and use its instance. JNI library is related to Java class. Change the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Log.i("MyTag", new MyNDK().getMyString());
   }
}
```

You can either export the **MyNDK** class as a jar package or create an **aar** bundle. Then import the Java class into your new project with JNI library.

The post [How to Build *.so Library Files into AAR Bundle in Android Studio](http://www.codepool.biz/build-so-aar-android-studio.html) may help you.

Comment: I’m trying to make an aar but so far got no luck... I’ll edit my question with some pics to show what I’ve done, please let me know if there's anything I missed, thanks a lot! :)